# I have a Dual boot with Windows and ubuntu running fine until last week, now the Dell XPS only boots windows

Tags: dual-boot

I am running Ubuntu dual-boot with Windows for several years.
Recently it only boots to Windows.
I have tried several solutions, like disabling fastStart, but without success.

Does anyone have a useful suggesting

Comment: Can you tell us about the boot order? Some UEFI settings list the Ubuntu boot device still as Windows Boot, just without the extended description which version of Windows is installed.

Comment: Windows update may reset boot order to Windows first. Ubuntu/grub major update also resets it to first in boot order. Also a Windows update may include an UEFI update, which resets many UEFI settings to defaults. If you had to change settings like AHCI, fast boot or Secure boot, you may have to redo those. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Thanks @oldfred, using bcdedit i changed the timeout from null to 15 seconds. Now i can reach the boot menu again